# how to do binary file to image(bmp etc) conversion in c++

Tags: c++, image, binary, converters

I have ultrasonic data from sensor available from my sensor and save as in a binary file xxx.bin I want to make an image from this file but unable to find the solution. After loads of search I come up with QT libraries, windows MFC etc.

Note that this binary file is just a simple raw data from my FPGA device. I need to make the image out of it. I have a program in LabVIEW that can do it, but now I have to make my system in C++ completely

any other idea would be appreciable

Comment: Why did you think you had to do it in C++?

Comment: because I am using a 3rd party DSP board where I have programmed FPGA and the communication with the PCIe-based board is through c++ APIs. Hope this answers

Comment: So I understood that you have to use C++ to fetch the ultrasonic data from your FPGA board, but do you have to use C++ for visualization, too?  Does the visualization have to be real-time?  Because C++ programs can be somewhat faster than Java, .NET or GNU R programs but the development work will be significantly more cumbersome for you.

Comment: yes you get it right. It is a real-time system. I am getting an idea now that it will be cumbersome, but this is the only way I have got. I suppose QT is not helpful for this purpose, it can only generate the GUI for system

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

Write the bytes to a simple image file and save as PGM image format. You can use GIMP software to view this image.

```
FILE *pFp = fopen("image.pgm", "wb");


int width = // get the width of the image ;
int height = // get the height of the image ;


UCHAR * start =  // get the starting location of the image data ;
if (pFp)
{
    //header of the pgm file
    fprintf(pFp, "P5\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", width, height, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i < height*width; i++)
    {
        putc(start[i],pFp);
    }
    fclose(pFp);
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply
I what I meant was that I need to make the image visible on the screen at run-time (with c++)

Comment: oh...Now that I see your code again. I think it can be beneficial for atleast saving the file as pgm format, later if this solution does not work I can try other thing. Thanks